# where is my port being blocked?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, port-forwarding

I'm trying to setup this software that allows me to use my laptop camera as surveillance and remotely access it via a website. I need to open a port that I can use to access the camera via a web browser. I setup rules in my windows firewall to open port range 8840-8860 but when I use www.portchecktool.com, they don't show as open and I can't get to my camera via the web browser with my external IP and port. But when I go to http://192.168.1.101:8848, the browser does load then, but I can't get it from the external IP. I did setup the rules in the router but still can't seem to get it to work.

My network is like this right now...Netgear Cable modem/wifi-router combo --> Linksys wireless router. I connect to the the Linksys wireless router. I also have norton 360 on my laptop as well. And the windows firewall is disabled.

On the netgear, I have port forwarding range from 8840-8850 to forward to 192.168.1.1 (linksys wifi router). The on the linksys, it forwards range 8840-8850 to 192.168.1.101 which is the IP address of the laptop with the camera.

Comment: do you have the software running on those ports? to be open from a specific sources location, a port must have a process listening on it, and a pathway from source to the process running on the port. if the software is not running, the port will still appear closed, because it is, even if the firewall is allowing those packets.

Comment: You need to forward all traffic on the given port the device's website is being ran on to the local intranet ip address assigned to said device.  All you have done is allowed traffic on your computer on those ports.

Comment: I need to clarify something, is your linksys wifi router in router or bridge mode ? Is it using NAT ? Is your netgear cable modem in bridge or router mode ?

Comment: linksys and the netgear are in router mode. Not sure if they are using NAT ( I dont think so ) as I can't find an option for NAT in both of the admin consoles for some reason. I see port forwarding, triggering and DMZ

Answer (score 0):

Rather than opening a port, you need to configure NAT (Network Address Translation) on the router.

This maps a port on your Internet facing IP address to another port on an internal facing IP address.

Exactly how you do this depends on the model of the router.